# How to test mac OS version in C

Tags: c++, c, macos

Typically, I would have done so:

```
SInt32 majorVersion, minorVersion;
Gestalt(gestaltSystemVersionMajor, &majorVersion);
Gestalt(gestaltSystemVersionMinor, &minorVersion);

bool is106 = majorVersion == 10 && minorVersion <= 6;
```

However `Gestalt` has been deprecated.

I've found various solution, from using `sysctl` or `operatingSystemVersionString` in obj-C.
New documented way being to use NSAppKitVersionNumber, but my code do not link against AppKit (and is in C++)

I need a plain C/C++, non deprecated method. And I can't find one :(

Edit: According to this doc: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/releasenotes/General/CarbonCoreDeprecations/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012224-CH1-SW16

using sysctl is the official way now

Comment: why you can link to AppKit?

Comment: And how will you even include the AppKit header in a C source code, I'd love to know :)

Comment: you don't need to include `<AppKit/AppKit.h>`, you can just copy & paste the declaration `NSAppKitVersionNumber` in one of your .h file.